# How to replace C# keywords with string subsitutes using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn

I'd like to use Roslyn to load C# sources and write it to another file, replacing keywords with substitutes. Sample:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){}
```

translated to

```
foobar (int i=0; i<10; i++){}
```

What the syntax for such operation could look like?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What have you tried?

Comment: Reason: translate program written in C# subset to arbitrary language with different syntax. I know how to modify tree, I don't know how to control token representation output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how well is this going to work, but you can replace each `ForKeyword` token with another `ForKeyword` token, but this time with your custom text. To do that, you can use `CSharpSyntaxRewriter`:

```
class KeywordRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxToken VisitToken(SyntaxToken token)
    {
        if (token.Kind() == SyntaxKind.ForKeyword)
        {
            return SyntaxFactory.Token(
                token.LeadingTrivia, SyntaxKind.ForKeyword, "foobar", "foobar",
                token.TrailingTrivia);
        }

        return token;
    }
}
```

Using this rewriter, you can write code like this:

```
string code = "for (int i=0; i<10; i++){}";

var statement = SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement(code);

var rewrittenStatement = new KeywordRewriter().Visit(statement);

Console.WriteLine(rewrittenStatement);
```

Which prints what you wanted:

```
foobar (int i=0; i<10; i++){}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look at creating a `SyntaxWalker` that walks over the entire tree and copies it to your output file, except for elements that are keyword tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record - following code also worked but accepted answer is much more elegant.

```
foreach (var t in tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot().DescendantTokens())
{

    if (t.HasLeadingTrivia)
    {
        file.Write(t.LeadingTrivia);
    }

    file.Write(t.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ForKeyword)? "foobar" : t.ToString());

    if (t.HasTrailingTrivia)
    {
        file.Write(t.TrailingTrivia);
    }

}
```