# C# alias for "new" keyword

Tags: c#

For example, you can alias the name of the class with:

```
using Rnd = System.Random;
```

But is there a way for creating an alias of "new"? So I would use `Random r = Novy Random()`, instead of `Random r = new Random()`.

Edit:

For explanation, I want to directly to call

```
Random r = Novy Random()
```

Not to rewrite it using Roslyn, but as stated it is not possible.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? IMO all that would achieve is that it would confuse everyone who reads your code

Comment: Would that make code so much more confusing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace C# keywords with string subsitutes using Roslyn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585869/how-to-replace-c-sharp-keywords-with-string-subsitutes-using-roslyn)

Comment: "Nový" is actualy new in my local.

Comment: @Kolichikov nope. This is actualy same, as replacing in string. I want to use it such as Rnd in example.

Comment: I see. If you're looking to specifically utilize the `using` keyword, then AKX has the answer - no, that's not supported.

Comment: @Kolichikov No, But I want to use `Random r = Novy Random()` instead of the normal syntax

Comment: This is a bad idea that will only lead to incomprehensible code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (not easily at all anyway).

`new` is a language keyword; you'd have to modify the C# parser itself.

Comment: So You can't create an alias for keyword such as for class?

Comment: Would it be C# then?

Comment: @rktech That's what I was saying. No, you can't.